# Currency output unsing number format class in java

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to use the number format class in order to have a double format into US currency,.

For example if tuition is 1000 ,I would need it to print out $1,000.00 .I will put a piece of code in to show where my trouble is.

The public double getCurrencyInstance() is the method that I started with and it's obviously incorrect.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class OnlineStudent extends Student {

    private double computingFee;

    public double getCurrencyInstance(){                
        return computingFee;                
    }

    public OnlineStudent(){                
        super();               
    }

    public OnlineStudent(String fName, String lName, String id,  int credits, double rate, double compFee){
        super(fName, lName, id, credits, rate);
        this.computingFee = compFee;
    }

    public void computeTuition(){
        tuition = (rate + computingFee) * creditNum;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return ("\nOnline Student:\nFirst name:\t\t" + firstName + "\nLast name:\t\t" + lastName + "\nStudent ID:\t\t" + studentID 
                + "\nCredits:\t\t" + creditNum + "\nRate:\t\t\t" + super.rate + "\nTuition:\t\t" + super.tuition + "\nComputing Fee:\t\t"
                + getCurrencyInstance() + "\n\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: take care when using floating point data types to model money

Comment: Please pay more attention to your code formatting in future - and don't use tabs, as they really don't play well with the Stack Overflow formatting.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Knowing that something is broken is very different to knowing how to fix it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't like the, imo, manipulative wording of their question: "It doesn't work, so I gave up. Give me answers." Op's imported `NumberFormat` but done nothing with it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I thought your response to it was significantly ruder than the question, to be honest. He's shown what he's tried, he knows it's *something* to do with `NumberFormat` but doesn't know how to use it. There's evidence of effort here, and I see no reason to be so abrupt to the OP.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll keep that in mind for the future, but I don't agree with the effort part.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance%28java.util.Locale%29), and then use *that* to format your value. For example:

```
public String toString() {
    NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    return "\nOnline Student:\nFirst name:\t\t" + firstName 
         + "\nLast name:\t\t" + lastName + "\nStudent ID:\t\t" + studentID 
         + "\nCredits:\t\t" + creditNum 
         + "\nRate:\t\t\t" + currencyFormat.format(super.rate)
         + "\nTuition:\t\t" + currencyFormat.format(super.tuition) 
         + "\nComputing Fee:\t\t" + currencyFormat.format(computingFee) + "\n\n");
}
```

I'd strongly advise you to use `BigDecimal` for currency values though, instead of `double`. I'd also reconsider `computeTuition` to *return* the tuition fee rather than just storing it in a field, but that's a different matter.

Comment: What benefit does `BigDecimal` provide for currency values?

Comment: @redFIVE: It means that you can represent typical values *exactly* - for example, 0.1 can't be exactly represented as a `double`, whereas it *can* be exactly represented in `BigDecimal`. Typically, you should use decimal-based types for "artificial" values such as money, where there really is the idea of "exactly a tenth of a dollar" and use `float` or `double` for natural quantities such as weight and length, where the value will never be exact anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and easy way to print standard currency amounts in e.g. UK locale, I use:

```
String.format("£%,.02f", pennies / 100.0);
```

This is probably the shortest code, and gives output the most common way currency values are formatted, like:

> £0.05
>
> £1.57
>
> £300.00
>
> £34,124.20
>
> £123,456,789.99

Obviously if you need to support different locales then this isn't sufficient (also, this is 'only' good for currency values up to 2^53...)